# How to create a movie from several .bmp-files under Linux?

Tags: linux, video, bmp

I have generated 90 .bmp files and now would like to generate a 3 second video with 30 frames per second from this. Preferrably in the .mov format, but any common format would be ok. Is there any (free) program available that can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ffmpeg` can create a .mov for you.

See [this section of the ffmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14).

You may like to try something such as:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 30 -i img%d.bmp ./out.mov
```

Comment: I just deleted my answer after re-reading the question.  This answer rocks!  You'll just need to make sure you have the correct codecs.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like a graphical interface, [Kino](http://kinodv.org/) will do this.

[image]

> Kino is a non-linear Digital Video
>   (DV) editor that supports video
>   capture in raw DV or AVI format (type
>   1 and type 2 DV, with separate audio
>   streams); loading of multiple video
>   and audio clips for editing, cutting
>   and pasting portions of those clips;
>   exporting the composite movie to DV
>   over IEEE 1394, raw DV, DV AVI, still
>   frames, WAV, MP3, Ogg Vorbis, MPEG-1,
>   MPEG-2, MPEG-4; **importing of still
>   frames in a variety of formats (eg,
>   GIF, TIFF, JPEG, PNG, PPM, BMP, SVG,
>   Targa, XPM);** audio and video playback;
>   multilingual interface; PAL and NTSC;
>   a variety of effects, audio and video
>   filters, video transitions, audio
>   transition (crossfade); etc. This is a
>   Linux program.