# Program for Ubuntu that can make a movie from a bunch of images?

Tags: ubuntu, video, images, editing, encoding

I need a program for Ubuntu that can take a bunch of sequential .png's and create a video. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffmpeg` can do this, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/79310/how-to-create-a-movie-from-several-bmp-files-under-linux/79315#79315) and the [FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC14).